# Getting this error in React while trying to build url for an image in sanity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, sanity

Server Error
Error: Malformed asset _ref 'e173af30-fd2d-42ed-a364-d92a2cddf32c'. Expected an id like "image-Tb9Ew8CXIwaY6R1kjMvI0uRR-2000x3000-jpg".[image]
[image]

Can someone help me to fix it please... actually i'm still learning while making this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding .url() to the src.

```
src={urlFor(image).url()}
```

If the image you're trying to render is stored directly on sanity as a link then you don't need urlFor().

```
src={image}
```